# How to define a method to be called from the configure block of a modular sinatra application?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app that, boiled down, looks basically like this:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  configure :production do
    myConfigVar = read_config_file()
  end

  configure :development do
    myConfigVar = read_config_file()
  end

  def read_config_file()
    # interpret a config file
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get `undefined method read_config_file for MyApp:Class (NoMethodError)`

The logic in `read_config_file` is non-trivial, so I don't want to duplicate in both. How can I define a method that can be called from both my configuration blocks? Or am I just approaching this problem in entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the `configure` block is executed as the file is read. You simply need to move the definition of your method before the configure block, and convert it to a class method:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  def self.read_config_file()
    # interpret a config file
  end

  configure :production do
    myConfigVar = self.read_config_file()
  end

  configure :development do
    myConfigVar = self.read_config_file()
  end

end
```

Comment: Brilliant! That works. Now I have to go read a ruby book to find out what the hell the difference is between `def methodname` and `def self.methodname`, which is new syntax to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your configure blocks are run when the class definition is evaluated. So, the context is the class itself, not an instance. So, you need a class method, not an instance method.

```
def self.read_config_file
```

That should work. Haven't tested though. ;)

Comment: I'm afraid using `self.read_config_file` gives exactly the same error. Sorry, I should have specified that I'd already tried this :-)

Comment: Damn it, I was **so close**. The second answerer is right. The class definition is interpreted as the file is read, and I guess those blocks are executed immediately by Sinatra, so you need to define the class method before you set up the configure lines.