# using configure in before block

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra version 1.1.0 I was able to use `configure` inside a `before` block. In version 1.4.5 this is no longer possible. Instead an error is thrown.

The error:

```
undefined method 'configure' for #<MySinatraServer:0x3f17a60>
file: web.rb location: block in <class:MySinatraServer> line:6
```

The class definition:

```
require 'sinatra'

class MySinatraServer < Sinatra::Base

  before do
    configure :production do
      halt 404, "insecure connection not allowed" if !request.secure?
    end
  end

  get '/' do
    "Hello Cruel World"
  end

end
```

Running with `thin start`, config.ru shown below:

```
map "/" do
  run MySinatraServer
end
```

Why does configure no longer work inside the before block?

Comment: Possibly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021869/how-to-define-a-method-to-be-called-from-the-configure-block-of-a-modular-sinatr) would help.

Comment: That'd be nice, but I can't access the `request` var outside of the before block. I wonder if I could access it through the Sinatra helpers though. Will give it a shot, thanks

Comment: @zishe unfortunately this got a bit messy... accessing the `request` var at class level was not so pretty. I managed to solve the problem another way, which seems relatively simple. See what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the `configure` block inside of the `before` block requires accessing the `settings` helper. The code now works.

Code here:

```
before do
  settings.configure :production do
    halt 404, "insecure connection not allowed" if !request.secure?
  end
end
```

Another gotcha is that the `after` block now runs when you `halt`. Ah the joys of upgrading framework versions!